# How can I avoid a TypeScript error with React useRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Using React Hooks, I run into a TypeScript error when I initialize a ref as null, then try to access it later. This is a pared-down, illustrative example:

```
  const el = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (el.current !== null) {
      //@ts-ignore
      const { top, width } = el.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
  }, []);

  return <div ref={el}></div>
```

The `@ts-ignore` suppresses the error `Object is possibly 'null'.` Is it possible to write this without getting the error?

Answer (score 19):

I found the answer here: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/hooks/#useref

The key is to assign a type to the ref:
`const el = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);`
then check carefully:

```
if (el && el.current){
  const { top, width } = el.current.getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

Comment: The in-depth explanation [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/38228#issuecomment-529749802).